# Is it possible to transfer the frequencies (pitch) between one audio file to another?

Tags: audio, data-transfer

If I have two audio files with the same duration, is it possible to alter the frequency of one file using the frequency of the other file? For example, my desired output would look like this:

Before frequency transfer:

| Timestamp | File A | File B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00:01 | 520 Hz | 870 Hz |
| 00:40 | 840 Hz | 530 Hz |

After frequency transfer:

| Timestamp | File A | **File B** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00:01 | 520 Hz | **520 Hz** |
| 00:40 | 840 Hz | **840 Hz** |

Think of this like autotune, except you're using the pitch from another audio file.

Comment: This seems like a really odd thing to want to do, could you explain the purpose? Are these disparate sounds? How complex is the waveform, simple sine, square etc or something complex & 'musical'. What's your curve, linear or logarithmic, or are you expecting it to track constantly & adjust accordingly?

Comment: This is mainly for experimental and entertainment purposes. I want to try altering songs using the data from other songs. My knowledge is pretty laymen, so I can't really explain the technical concepts behind this idea.

Comment: You'll need something like Melodyne, which is about the only app that can pick out a single tune from in amongst an entire mix & re-tune it. It's not a toy, it needs expertise, & it's not cheap.

Comment: Based on some communication tech; you might find something interesting if you look up and ponder on "amplitude modulation", or even "modulation" in general. It might be it can be applied in a way the suits as "answer" for you. I believe sound can be modulated in similar manner.

Comment: Unclear: what time resolution is needed, for example, µseconds or seconds?

Comment: I think you're coming at this from the wrong end entirely. If you're dealing in music you need to think in music, not in frequencies. Any of the autotune clones can move any note to anywhere; once it's been analysed you can drag notes to wherever you want them [whether that will sound good or not is not at issue]. You didn't say exactly what your input is - if it's more than a simple, solo melody, you will not get it to work without Melodyne.